# Deploying JavaFx application on Server

Tags: javafx-2

I have a sample Java Fx application(Helloworld). I am trying to deploy it on the *apache tomcat server*.

I have placed *.jar*, *.jnlp* and *.html* file into Tomcat's *webapps/ROOT directory*. Started the tomcat.
When I  try to access my application via *"HelloWorld.html*", I am getting below mentioned error.

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: WIExplorerMy not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.services.WPlatformService$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.services.WPlatformService.getBrowserClientAuthKeyStore(Unknown 
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: WIExplorerMy KeyStore not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
```

Any inputs on the same.

Also is there any other way to deploy JavaFx application on any servers.

Comment: I signed the jar and deployed again. I am getting a different error.

Comment: com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: C:\Users\skm6kor/Local Settings/Temporary Internet Files/contentIES/HelloWorld.jnlp                               
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload

Comment: I tried adding the below code in HelloWorld.jnlp file. But no diffrerence                                                     <j2se version="1.6.10+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"
      java-vm-args="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"/>                               Any inputs in this regard will be appreciated a lot.